# How is default readahead value determined

Tags: filesystems, raid, xfs

I have two different devices running XFS and the default readahead value set differs between the two disks. Why is that ? How is the default size computed ? Is it device dependent ?

I might also add that the devices are RAID disks and I use `blockdev --getra` to see the readahead value.